# Security Testing for brute force attacks on login page

Tags: automated-testing, security-testing, penetration

I want to perform testing for brute force attacks on login page of a website. I am new to security testing and I think i can test this by multiple failed login attempts. I wrote the below code to test this but i am not sure which test tool would be good to use and how can i perform this testing on the tool. Could someone please suggest me the tool and educate how would this test can be done by using same tool?

```
    List<Long> attempts = loginFails.get(login);
if (attempts != null) {
    synchronized(attempts) {
        if (attempts.size() == ATTEMPTS_TO_FREEZE 
            && attempts.peek() > System.currentTimeMillis() - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(TIME_FRAME_IN_MINUTES)) 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Swati there are many tools like burpsuite , OWASP zap , fiddler that act as proxy server and could be used for brute forcing or fuzzing. There is also tools like metasploit that can be used , what is your exact requirement

Comment: @Swati Mittal - Thanks for accepting the answer, if you have found it useful then please upvote it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below url has provided the definition of Brute Force Attack as well as tools which help to perform such testing:

https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/popular-tools-for-brute-force-attacks/#gref